# Show keyboard on a canvas (mobile / tablets)

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, keyboard, babylonjs

I used babylonjs to develop a small webgl application showing in a canvas.

Users can interact with the animation using the arrow keys (see https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/interactions#keyboard-interactions).

On desktop, it works perfectly OK. On mobile, the keyboard doesn't show up because there is not text input, so the arrows cannot be used.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

1- simple Way :

you can  design a panel with 4 buttons and allow user pressing them ...   and place it over your canvas